# Failed to send get core worker stats request

Tags: ray

I test ray on local with different machines. Most of them run fine but one of these got `(pid=raylet) E0515 16:26:30.978312 358451 node_manager.cc:3537] Failed to send get core worker stats request: IOError: 8: Sent message larger than max (290460356 vs. 104857600)` this warning. And the performance in this machine dose lower then others. If there are any connections between them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When Ray head cluster is initialized, it starts a built-in dashboard which collects metrics across the cluster. I guess since your cluster is really large, some of this requests exceed the max request size.

In this case, you can turn off the dashboard. You can do this by setting an argument --include-web-ui when you launch the head node. For example,

If you launch the head node from the script.

```py
ray.init(include_webui=False)
```

If you launch the head node using the command line tool

```sh
ray start --include-webui=False
```